# Is there a disconnect event for io.on()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, socket.io

I found the the [server documentation](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/) but could not find documentation specifically for events detected on the server.

The first mention of **io.on()** is [here](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99) in the the Namespace section.

```
io.on('connect', (socket) => {
  // ...
});
```

One confusing part is that the server object is shown as **server** in some cases and as **io** in other cases.

All other mentions use the same event - **connection**.

I was hoping their would be documentation that lists the evens for **io.on()** some where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no disconnect event on the server object even though there is a connect event.

I think you did not notice that io is the server object and so there is plenty of documentation on the server object.

Answer (score 0):

The "disconnect" event is at the socket level. You can read about it here: [Event: ‘disconnect’](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Event-%E2%80%98disconnect%E2%80%99)

The 3 events at the socket level are listed at the bottom of the Socket section of that API page and are as follows:

1. [Event: ‘disconnect’](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Event-%E2%80%98disconnect%E2%80%99)
2. [Event: ‘error’](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Event-%E2%80%98error%E2%80%99)
3. [Event: ‘disconnecting](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Event-%E2%80%98disconnecting%E2%80%99)

Comment: Weird how there is documentation for `socket.on()` but not `io.on()` ...

Comment: Not sure what is weird about it. The "disconnect" event is not emitted at the "server" level, e.g. "io". It is a "client" (e.g. "socket") event. When a connection is made a socket is created. It is that socket we are interested in knowing if it disconnects, right?

Comment: What is weird is that their is no documentation for `io.on()`. Not the fact that a disconnect event occurs on the socket object.

Comment: @j.a. There is plenty of documentation for `io.on()`. The problem with documentation, it's _worthless_ if you don't understand what you are reading. Here you go. The documentation for the one and only, single, top level event built into the server: [Event: ‘connect’](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99). The rest of the documentation for any [Class: EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) in [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/): [emitter.on(eventName, listener)](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look at it, I couldn't find a direct `disconnect` event on `io`, but apparently you can watch the socket *within* the callback of the io/server object for a [disconnect event](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Event-%E2%80%98disconnect%E2%80%99).

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

---

EDIT: A much better explanation from [gforce301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1819684/gforce301):

> You can, and probably should, store a reference to the created socket.
>
> If the event were on "io" (the server), then we would essentially be
> watching the server itself disconnect. That's not what really happens
> though.
>
> The server itself is never really "connected" or
> "disconnected". Sockets (clients) are "connected" and "disconnected"
> to and from the server.

Comment: I'm guessing that is because it is possible to disconnect from the socket but not close the connection. So they're different things.

Comment: You don't have to "watch it _within_ the callback. You can, and probably should, store a reference to the created socket. If the event were on "io" (the server), then we would essentially be watching the server itself disconnect. That's not what really happens though. The server itself is never really "connected" or "disconnected". Sockets (clients) are "connected" and "disconnected" to and from the server.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for explaining it so much better! I'll update my answer to include this.

Comment: @j.a. I'm not trying to be snarky here (though I'm sure someone will think that I am). What you're saying doesn't make any sense at all. A socket object is not created **until** a _connection_ is made and handed to the callback. What are you suggesting to solve your _asymmetrical_ issue? Are you suggesting that we just have a bunch of unused socket objects laying around just in case a connection is made? How do you propose to add event handlers to these non-existent socket objects _**in code**_? I've been a software engineer a long time and I would like to see that example code please.